# Choice of reduction polynomial in Whirlpool's internal cipher

Tags: algorithm-design, finite-field, rijndael, mds, miyaguchi-preneel

[Whirlpool](http://www.larc.usp.br/~pbarreto/WhirlpoolPage.html) is an interesting little hash function in the Miyaguchi-Preneel family.

In my mind, it's most interesting feature is the design of internal cipher W, where the distinction between key and message is dropped, providing a symmetric symmetric cipher. This conceivably removes the need to test for weaknesses to related-key attacks, since if you can do something in the key you could just do it in the message, and makes a lot of sense as a hash function internal.

However, **why did they change the field polynomial from that used in AES?**

> **Table 1: Differences between RIJNDAEL and W**
>
> <kbd>RIJNDAEL</kbd>                                      <kbd>W</kbd>                                                      
>   <kbd>Block size (bits)</kbd>                          <kbd>128, 160, 192, 224, or 256</kbd>             <kbd>always 512</kbd>                                       
>   <kbd>Number of rounds</kbd>                       <kbd>10, 11, 12, 13, or 14</kbd>                       <kbd>always 10</kbd>                                         
>   <kbd>Key schedule</kbd>                              <kbd>dedicated a *priori* algorithm</kbd>            <kbd>the round function itself</kbd>                    
>   <kbd>$GF(2^8)$ reduction polynomial</kbd>   
>
> <kbd>(0x11B)                                           
> $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$</kbd><kbd>(0x11D)                                            
> $x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1$</kbd>
>   <kbd>Origin of the S-box</kbd>                     
>
> <kbd>mapping u → u-1 over $GF(2^8)$,   
> plus affine transform</kbd><kbd>recursive structure (see below)</kbd>      
>
>
>   <kbd>Origin of the round constants</kbd>    <kbd>polynomials $x^i$ over $GF(2^8)$</kbd>        <kbd>successive entries of the S-box</kbd>     
>   <kbd>Diffusion layer</kbd>                            
>
>
> <kbd>left-multiplication by the                   
>
>   4×4 circulant MDS matrix
>
>   cir(2, 3, 1, 1)</kbd><kbd>right-multiplication by the                 
>
>   8×8 circulant MDS matrix
>
>   cir(1, 1, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2, 9)</kbd>
>
> <sup>The **W** S-box, which in the original submission is generated entirely at random (i.e. lacks any internal structure), by a recursive structure: the new 8×8 substitution box is composed of smaller 4×4 "mini-boxes" (the exponential E-box, its inverse, and the pseudo-randomly generated R-box).</sup>

More generally, why were several of the internal constants and methods changed?

Comment: nb: If someone wants to copy up the comparison table here they're more than welcome - the lack of table support on SE stopped me. Also, I have not tagged this with hash because its not actually about hash functions - its about a symmetric cipher that I've only seen used inside a particular hash function.

Comment: *"If someone wants to copy up the comparison table..."* - Done.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [original NESSIE submission](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/workshop/submissions.html) of Whirlpool:

> "The ﬁnite ﬁeld ${\rm GF}(2^8)$ will be represented as ${\rm GF}(2)[x]/p(x)$, where $p(x) =$ $x^8 +$ $x^4 +$ $x^3 +$ $x^2 +$ $1$ is the ﬁrst primitive polynomial of degree $8$ listed in [19]. The polynomial $p(x)$ was chosen so that $g(x) = x$ is a generator of ${\rm GF}(2^8) \setminus \{0\}$."

The reference "[19]" is to Lidl & Niederreiter, [*Introduction to Finite Fields and Their Applications*](//books.google.com/books?id=AvY3PHlle3wC) (Cambridge Univ. Press, 1986), which indeed, in Appendix 2, Table C, lists all the irreducible polynomials of degree 8 over ${\rm GF}(2)$ in lexicographic order.  The first of these, $p(x) =$ $x^8 +$ $x^4 +$ $x^3 +$ $x +$ $1$, is the AES polynomial, and is [irreducible](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) but not [primitive](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_%28field_theory%29).  The second one is the Whirlpool polynomial given above, and is the first primitive polynomial in the list.

Honestly, though, I have no idea why Whirlpool would require a primitive reduction polynomial, while Rijndael does not.

It *might* have something to do with a primitive polynomial allowing more efficient implementation on low-end platforms.
In particular, as the Whirlpool submission notes, for primitive reduction polynomials, $g(x) = x$ is a generator of the full multiplicative group of the field, and, at least at a glance, the suggested implementation of the MDS matrix multiplication on 8-bit processors in the Whirlpool paper appears to make some use of this fact.

Comment: Ps. See also [this related question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/251/design-properties-of-the-rijndael-finite-field).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ilmari - and thank you 'Quarterly Reviews'!

Answer (score 2):

I guess that a single e-mail to Vincent Rijmen might solve this problem, but I would speculate that the new S-box should have been more hardware-friendly compared to that of Rijndael. The recursive structure of $W$ and smaller constants in the MDS matrix may have required another field representation.