# How are the AES S-Boxes calculated?

Tags: aes, s-boxes

I'm trying to understand how the AES S-Boxes are calculated. I understand how the multiplicative inverse is calculated over $GF(2^8)$, but I'm confused by the description of the affine transformation. I haven't been able to Google a good explanation of how the S-Box values are calculated. Can someone explain how this works, starting after the calculation of the multiplicative inverse?

Comment: Just in case you're also looking for the design decisions of the fixed S-Boxes and how Rijmen calculated them, check out ["The Design of Rijndael: AES - The Advanced Encryption Standard"](http://books.google.de/books/about/The_Design_of_Rijndael.html) by Joan Daemen and Vincent Rijmen. It's a good read and explains it all.

Comment: [This](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/99/5231) is a partial (at least) answer to your question

Comment: Page 50,51 of [The Block Cipher Companion](http://www.springer.com/computer/security+and+cryptology/book/978-3-642-17341-7) provide a clear explanation of how the S-box is designed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The affine transformation works similar to MixColumns, but operates on an array of 8 bits instead of 4 bytes. Confusion in various descriptions of the affine transform in AES comes from where the LSB of the input byte is located. Some show it at the top of the column, others show it at the bottom. I will be using the version shown in the Rijndael paper, with the LSB at the top of the column.

The matrix used in AES is a rotational matrix based on the value `0x1F`, which is `00011111` in binary. The multiplication is performed in the field GF(2), as is the addition of the final vector `0x63`. Addition in GF(2) is the same as xor.

The bit indexes for the matrix are `76543210`, with `0` being the least significant bit and `7` being the most significant. Each column is the previous column rotated to the left by a single bit, as shown here:

```
0  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
1  0  7  6  5  4  3  2
2  1  0  7  6  5  4  3
3  2  1  0  7  6  5  4
4  3  2  1  0  7  6  5
5  4  3  2  1  0  7  6
6  5  4  3  2  1  0  7
7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

For the AES 0x1F affine matrix, the bits are arranged in the following way:

```
1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1
1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1
1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1
1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0
0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
```

For an input of `0x53` in AES, we first find its inverse, which is `0xCA`, represented in binary as `11001010`

The affine transformation is as follows. The input bits are multiplied against the bits of a given row, with the first bit the LSB of the input. Input bit 0 is only multiplied by row bit 0, and so on. Only when both values are one (logical AND) is the result one. Finally, all bits are XORd against eachother within that row to generate the transformed bit for that row.

```
Input = 0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1 (LSB First)
Row 0 = 1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
Bit 0 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1 = 0

Row 1 = 1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1
Bit 1 = 0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1 = 1

Row 2 = 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1
Bit 2 = 0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1 = 1

Row 3 = 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1
Bit 3 = 0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1 = 1

Row 4 = 1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
Bit 4 = 0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0 = 0

Row 5 = 0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
Bit 5 = 0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0 = 0

Row 6 = 0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0
Bit 6 = 0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0 = 0

Row 7 = 0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
Bit 7 = 0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1 = 1
```

The final result LSB first is `01110001` or MSB first is `10001110 = 0x8E`. This value is then added (XOR) to the final vector `0x63`, giving an output of `0xED`

Comment: I understand how this works but I cannot understand why the algorithm presented in the wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box#Forward_S-box) page is equivalent.

Comment: I think I got it. It was, actually, trivial. ;-)

Comment: Maybe a litte bit late, can you elaborate on how bits are XOR'd against each other in one bit row?

Comment: @ThomasWagenaar Bit 7 = 0 xor 0 xor 0 xor 1 xor 0 xor 0 xor 1 xor 1 = 1

Comment: How did you get the inverse of 0x53? I'm finding that 0x53 doesn't have any inverse

Comment: @DheerajMPai because thats what it is when you calculate it, the only one that does not have an inverse is 0x00