# How are calculated numbers in AES S-box?

Tags: aes, s-boxes

I have a problem calculating the `0x02` value of the AES S-Box.

I followed the steps descibed in “[How are the AES S-Boxes calculated?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/how-are-the-aes-s-boxes-calculated/)”, but my answer is not correct.

`0x02` is 00000010

```
Input = 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 (LSB First)
Row 0 = 1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
Bit 0 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 = 1

Row 1 = 1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1
Bit 1 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 = 1

Row 2 = 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1
Bit 2 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 = 1

Row 3 = 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1
Bit 3 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 = 0

Row 4 = 1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
Bit 4 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 = 0

Row 5 = 0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
Bit 5 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 = 0

Row 6 = 0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0
Bit 6 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 = 1

Row 7 = 0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
Bit 7 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 = 1
```

LSB is 11100011, MSB = 11000111, than (XOR) to the final vector 0x63,
the result is `0xa4`, but it should be `0x77`

What am I missing or what might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to compute the inverse of `02` first. The inverse of `02` is `8d` (as $02 \cdot 8d = 01$ in the AES $GF(2^8)$ representation). You then apply the affine transform to the value `8d`.