# How are the AES inverse S-Boxes calculated?

Tags: aes, s-boxes

I would like to know, how to calculate the inverse S-box.
I followed [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/how-are-the-aes-s-boxes-calculated)
link (with affine transformation first, then multiplicative inverse), but the result is wrong. For example, if I use the value `0x52` (01010010 in binary), reverse of this value would be 01001010.
The inverse matrix (for inverse S-Box) is:

[image]

```
Input = 0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0 (LSB First)
Row 0 = 0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1
Bit 0 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 = 0

Row 1 = 1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
Bit 1 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 = 1

Row 2 = 0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1
Bit 2 = 0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0 = 0

Row 3 = 1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0
Bit 3 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 = 0

Row 4 = 0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0
Bit 4 = 0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0 = 0

Row 5 = 0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
Bit 5 = 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 = 1

Row 6 = 1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0
Bit 6 = 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 = 0

Row 7 = 0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0
Bit 7 = 0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0 = 1
```

The result is `01000101`, MSB first that would be `10100010`, XOR-ed with final vector `0x52` is `0xf0`. The inverse of `0xf0` is `0x5b`, which is wrong. It should be `0x48`. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: It is not clear how your inverse S-box is calculated exactly. It must be: 1) XOR 0x63; 2) Apply the matrix that is the inverse to the 0x1F matrix; 3) Compute the inverse in GF(256).

Comment: how did you get the reverse of 0x52 is 0x4A?
would you like to explain this? I've been looking for this in two days

Comment: @PanduHutagalung Check this: https://github.com/bpdegnan/aes/blob/master/aes-sbox/documentation/aessbox.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You performed the matrix component of the affine tranformation correctly, what you did wrong was the addition of the vector prior to field inversion.

The value `10100010 (0xA2)` is the correct result of the inverse affine matrix. The final vector of the inverse affine transform however is `00000101 (0x05)`.

The resultant `0xA7` is then inverted, which is `0x48`, the correct inverse s-box value.