# How to calculate the Inverse of random AES S-BOX (asuming we don't know how the S-BOX built)?

Tags: aes, s-boxes

I'm recently studying cryptography, and I have a task for collecting the s-boxes for AES, and then implementing that s-boxes for encrypting & decrypting, but most of the S-boxes I found are not including the inverse of it.

I know that most of it gives the calculation on how to construct the s-box and the inverse, but I don't think I can make it in time if I do that.

So, I wonder is any method of calculating the inverse of random AES S-BOXes?

Comment: In python: if `S` is an ordered list of S-box entries `SInverse=[S.index(i) for i in range(256)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SageMath has a great [S-Box](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/sbox.html) package that is heavily used by S-Box designers. If you are going to learn/play with S-Boxes you may benefit from this package.

With Sbox Package ([Try online](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVjcEKwjAQRO_5iqVesiABL17Ei18gtHdpddsGTDZstrb-vSkU1DkNw-NNLxwgtwO5u7yTsssdL-BDYlGoL7wYswtTVugIEs8kwD3ozMA6ksw-E5AIi0lwhitJmLRVzzFbaeNA9nBEdKU-ONzoSYGiWjSmLvRqtwlPJokva9WM5eJrgC3VHmr8ZXx8keQ_dmXctlvED8r9R4g=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==))

```
from sage.crypto.sbox import SBox

#must be power of two otherwise error
p = Permutations(range(16)).random_element()

S = SBox(p);
print("The permutation        ", S)
print("The inverse permutation", S.inverse())
```

SageMath currently using Python3, so one can write their version very easily either in Python or SageMath ([Try online](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwLULBVCEgtyi0tSSzJzM8r1ihKzEtP1TA009TUAzJT8nPjU3NSc1PzSjQ0ubgKijKBDKWQjFSFAoQmBShQ0lEIACryzCtLLSpODbCNDtDLzEtJrdDI1FRIyy9SyFTIzFOAmx-LbFomRA-yqUDTYCZpAgCSCjZN&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==));

```
P = Permutations(range(16)).random_element()

print("The permutation        ", P)

InverseP=[P.index(i) for i in range(16)]
print("The inverse permutation", InverseP)
```

As we can see the S-Box package is much better, for example, the construction checks that the size is equal to a power of 2 or not.

---

**Note:** I've used random permutations to guarantee that the inverse exists.

---

As we can see from the [Sbox package source](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/a89f81d7783df2d4e4a187bf209e94d128301f83/src/sage/crypto/sbox.py#L1655)

```
m = self.input_size()
L = [self(i) for i in range(1<<m)]
return SBox([L.index(i) for i in range(1<<m)], big_endian=self._big_endian)
```

SageMath converts S-Box into a List, takes the inverse on the list then constructs a S-Box on the list. As we can see the inverse - if exist - is not magic.

Comment: Hi, Can your answer in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63095/how-we-can-calculate-aes-inverse-sbox) be considered an alternative answer?

Comment: @CatDragon  Sure, different questions and different approaches to the same subject.