# Variants of AES?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, algorithm-design, mds

Would variants of AES provide the same level of security as AES, say by just replacing the S-box with another one, MDS matrix of Mixcolumn, etc.?

Comment: What research did you do? I’m asking, because you seem to be unaware of already existing questions like… [***Replacing the Rijndael S-Box?***](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/98/12164)

Answer (score 3):

There is book [Algebraic Aspects of the Advanced Encryption Standard](https://www.springer.com/computer/security+and+cryptology/book/978-0-387-24363-4) thats gives a good algebraic description of the AES algorithm. Reading it you'll see that there was some freedom in choosing some parametres to fix a standard. Changing this choices, but keeping the algebric properties should give you an equivalent algorithm. 
This mainly means you can change the irreductible polynomial used to define the field, ...