# In AES is 0x11b is the specified field generator?

Tags: aes

As I know all arithmetic operations in AES are done over $GF(2^8)$ so I want to know which field generator AES uses? is it 0x11B? and choosing another field generator would it give a different results?

Comment: Related [Design properties of the Rijndael finite field?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/251/design-properties-of-the-rijndael-finite-field?rq=1) and [Replacing the Rijndael S-Box?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/98/replacing-the-rijndael-s-box) Pancho's answer : `Actually, the choice of irreducible polynomial is unimportant in AES; for any polynomial representation of `$GF(2^8)$

Comment: @kelalaka sorry for the following stupid question but would you kindly answer it : is irreducible polynomial is same as the field generator? if not what is the relation? and is $x^{8}+x^{3}+x+1$ is the same 0x11b?

Comment: See [Why generator polynomial of $GF(2^m)$
are irreducible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280632/why-generator-polynomial-of-gf2m-are-irreducible) for a complete answer

Comment: The binary representation of $0x11b$ is $100011011$, which corresponds to the polynomial $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ (you forgot the $x^4$ term, and yes, this is the field generator used by AES. You should use it, if you care not just about the theoretical security, but also about getting the correct result.

Comment: A different generator would result in a different incompatible cipher. The choice of generator shouldn't influence the security, but you shouldn't use a generator which hasn't received as much scrutiny at the one in the standard. The generator in the standard had to be a nothing-up-my-sleeve number.